# Sort even and odd part of array

Tags: java

I am kind of stuck with this logic . lets say i have and array of `int` . What i need is separate the Even number and odd numbers  i.e all even number should come first in sorted order and then all odd number in sorted order . 
**This needs to be done with array only not collection.**
input will be.

```
int[] a ={3,2,5,6,4,9,11,7}
```

Output should be as

```
{2,4,6,3,5,7,9,11}
```

My approach was:-
1. first separate the even and odd .  
2. Then find the last_index-of_even_number . 
 
3. Then sort the array first `0-last_index-of_even_number` and then `last_index-of_even_number- arr.length`.

But i think its not a good approach. Can anyone help me to this logic correct with algo and code example .

Comment: What makes you think that's not a good approach?

Comment: Cause in this approach i have to iterate the Array 3 times .

Comment: Sorting will be n*log(n) anyways. A few extra passes isn't a huge deal.

Answer (score 4):

Apply any sorting algorithm and use as a comparator a function that considers even numbers "smaller" than odd numbers. This enables you to use a good sorting algorithm while still sorting the elements the way you want to.

This is my gnome sort implementation and my compare function:

```
private static void sort(int[] arr) {
    int index = 0;
    int n = arr.length;
    while (index < n) {
        if (index == 0)
            index++;
        if (compare(arr[index], arr[index - 1]))
            index++;
        else {
            int temp = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[index - 1];
            arr[index - 1] = temp;
            index--;
        }
    }
}

private static boolean compare(int a, int b) {
    if (a % 2 == b % 2) return a > b;
    return a % 2 == 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 9, 11, 7};

    sort(a);

    for (int i : a) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Works fine. Try other sorting algorithms though.

TL;DR: instead of comparing items using "<" and ">" , use a function.

Comment: Small simplification of compare: if (a % 2 == b % 2) return a > b;

Comment: @Uli I should've noticed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution

1. sort the input array.
2. create a concrete `List`.  Use what ever implementation you want; `LinkedList` seems appropate.
3. run the input array, one time.  For every even number, add it to the `List`.
4. run the input array, one more time.  For every add number, add it to the `List`.
5. Convert the `List` to an array (read the Java API pages for this).

If you assume that the sort is `n*log(n)`,
it now becomes `n*log(n) + 2` which,
I believe,
reduces back to `n*log(n)`.

Solution with clown limitations (or, perhaps, unadmitted student homework limitation)

1. Sort the input array.
2. Create a new array that is the same size as the input array (call it the target array).
3. Run through the input array (by index). For every even number, add it to the target array.
4. Run through the input array (by index). For every odd number, add it to the target array.
5. Do what you want with the target array (perhaps, copy it to the input array).

Same Big-O as with the `List` if you sort using a quick sort.

Comment: Seems quite fair to in term of complexity . So can you tell me if i go with array only and no use of Collection is there a better approach or logic so that i can make it work in less than 3 iteration .

Answer (score 2):

Moving around things in arrays is not that efficient since data are stored sequentially.If you don't want to use another structure you could instead sort a first O(nlogn).While sorting you can easily count how many even numbers you have, so you know the position of the first odd number. Then create a second array let's say b and add to it all even numbers from a starting from 0 and odd numbers starting from the position of the first odd number.You can do this in O(n), one parse

```
//sort a first
//find odd_index --> 3 in your case

int even_index=0;
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    if(a[i]%2==0){
        b[even_index]=a[i];
        even_index++;
    }else{
        b[odd_index]=a[i];
        odd_index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow . If this work this can be the solution i was looking for . Can you please add the full code .

Answer (score 2):

look at this solution:

```
 public class Test 
 {
   static int [] oddEvenSort(int arr[]){
     int temp[] = new int [arr.length];
     int evenIndex = 0;
     int oddIndex = arr.length - 1;
    arr = sort(arr);
     for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++)
     {

         if((arr[i] & 1) == 0){
             temp[evenIndex] = arr[i];
             evenIndex += 1;
         }else
         {
             temp[oddIndex] = arr[i];
            oddIndex -= 1;
         }
     }
    return temp;
 }

 static  int [] sort(int arr[]){
      for(int i=0; i< arr.length;i++)
     {
         for(int j = i;j < arr.length;j++)
         {
         if(arr[j] < arr[i]){
             int temp = arr[i];
             arr[i] = arr[j];
             arr[j] = temp;
         }
         }
     }
     return arr;
 }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 3, 2, 7, 5, 4};

    oddEvenSort(arr, arr.length);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
 }
}
```

Comment: You can simply replace it with your sorting algo. Logic is there apart from the sorting

Comment: fair enough .. +1 . 3 steps with all approach i have checked  . I think this is all its gonna take 3 minimum.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is take two treemap in java. One for even numbers and one for odd numbers. while iterating the numbers place even numbers in even treemap and odd numbers in odd treemap. after that merge both treemap in one list first even then odd.

I think this will work in your case.

Comment: NO Collection . I also added it in question . I just need a  logic .